# Could not add padding to checkboxes in android

Tags: android

I've introduced 2 checkboxes in my UI screen and I want these checkboxes to some distance apart (50dp). I've put padding in my second checkbox (@+id/chkbox2) but the padding does not seem to be working. The second checkbox is placed immediately next to first checkbox. I'm new to Android and I've been trying for the past 1 day but could not add the padding. Below is my xml file, please let me know if I'm missing something.

---

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:background="#f0f0f0"
     android:orientation="vertical">

  <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp" android:text="HEADER"
    android:background="#614767"
    android:textSize="32sp" 
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingLeft="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/header"
    />

   <ImageView
        android:layout_height="46dp" 
        android:src="@drawable/logo_web" 
        android:id="@+id/logo" 
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        />

   <TextView android:id="@+id/textView11" 
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="55dp"
                 android:textSize="30sp" 
                 android:paddingLeft="15dp" 
                 android:textColor="#000000"
                 android:gravity="center" 
                 android:layout_below="@+id/header"/>

       <include android:layout_below="@+id/textView11"
       layout="@layout/second" />

    <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chkbox1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/camera_preview"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" 
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:textSize="20sp" 
                 android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/chkbox1"
                 android:layout_below="@+id/camera_preview"/>

           <ImageView
            android:layout_height="60dp" 
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/chkbox1"/> 

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chkbox2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/chkbox1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/camera_preview"/>

           <TextView android:id="@+id/textView2" 
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:textSize="10sp" 
                 android:paddingLeft="10dp" 
                 android:layout_below="@+id/camera_preview"
                 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/chkbox2"/>

           <ImageView
            android:layout_height="100dp" 
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/view2" 
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/chkbox2"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/view1"/>  

           <TextView android:id="@+id/textView3" 
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:textSize="10sp" 
                 android:paddingLeft="85dp"
                 android:layout_below="@+id/camera_preview" 
                 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"/>

           <ImageView
            android:layout_height="100dp" 
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/view3" 
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/view2"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_height="40dp" 
            android:text="@string/back2"
            android:textSize="19sp" 
            android:textColor="#01a982"
            android:id="@+id/cancel" 
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@color/border"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_height="40dp" 
            android:text="@string/shutter"
            android:textSize="19sp" 
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:id="@+id/takepicture" 
            android:layout_width="95dp"
            android:background="#01a982"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cancel"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
            />

        <Button
            android:layout_height="40dp" 
            android:text="@string/submit"
            android:textSize="19sp" 
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:id="@+id/submit" 
            android:layout_width="95dp"
            android:background="#01a982"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/takepicture"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
            />


        <Button
            android:layout_height="40dp" 
            android:text="@string/delete3"
            android:textSize="19sp" 
            android:textColor="#01a982"
            android:id="@+id/delete" 
            android:layout_width="95dp"
            android:background="@color/border"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/submit"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
            />

     </RelativeLayout>
```

---

My second xml file ("@layout/second"):

---

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
        android:layout_width="420dp"
        android:layout_height="385dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView11">
        </FrameLayout>
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the padding to margin:

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/chkbox2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/chkbox1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/camera_preview"/>
```